# Google Search - Url pattern - One result per domain

Tags: search, google-custom-search, keyword-search

I'm trying to search google for a url pattern: "/travel-" and limit my search results to one per domain.

Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
allinurl: "/travel-*"

inurl: "/travel-*"

site: "/travel-*"
```

Not sure how to get desired result...

Also if another url crawler tool exists that does this functionality, don't hesitate to point it out!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 0**

[This user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/23321/daleswanson) on Web Applications StackExchange created a GreaseMoneky script to help with the problem.

> Well, I wrote a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script to fix this,
>   http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/141480.html.
>
> I don't have much JavaScript experience, but it seems to work well
>   enough. I'm still amazed no one else had written something like this
>   yet. It was driving me crazy.

via https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30015/prevent-many-results-from-same-domain-in-google-search

More Information on the Script:

- Hide multiple results from one domain in google
- By [daleswanson](http://userscripts-mirror.org/users/99729.html) — Last update Nov 27, 2013 — Installed 1,573 times.
- http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/141480.html

**Solution 1**

[Folks on this forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4699959-2-30.htm) suggest using DuckDuckGo as it returns less duplicate domains than Google. Example travel query: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=travel

Comment: Solution 0 Seems useful to limit to one result per domain, however doesn't have exact url desired: "/travel-", could modify script and go from there, looks good!

Solution 1, can't search for exact string in url and can't limit results per domain.

Comment: The results from DuckDuckGo are just a little better. There are no ways to limit results per domain. Solution 0 will probably be your best bet. There are a lot discussions on this problem, but not a whole lot of solutions or workarounds.

Comment: @LucLaverdure, this answers your question. Why not accept the answer or at least up vote helpful answers?

Comment: Won't accept yet as I didn't review the answer, but it is helpful, swamped lately, but thanks for guidance!

Comment: Understand. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do the same as the script above, but the following all work fine to limit it to a single response per search:

```
www.google.com/search?q=allinurl%3A+"%2Ftravel-*"&oq=allinurl%3A+"%2Ftravel-*"&num=1

www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3A+"%2Ftravel-*"&oq=inurl%3A+"%2Ftravel-*"&num=1

www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+"%2Ftravel-*"&oq=site%3A+"%2Ftravel-*"&num=1
```

I shall work on a domain limiting method via the API/arguments over the next few days:)

Comment: "num" parameter seems to limit to x results, which is not desired functionality.

Comment: ahh sorry got the wrong end of the stick then, will redress that as soon as I can:)